# Chef-Server fails startup

Tags: debian-squeeze, lxc, chef

I've installed chef-server from the chef apt repository [using these instructions](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Installing+Chef+Server+on+Debian+or+Ubuntu+using+Packages) and everything seems to work until I try to start chef-server.

I'm running Debian Squeeze in a Linux container (LXC).

This is an example of the output I get when I try to start chef-server:

```
Starting chef-server : ~ In 4977
failed!
```

There does not seem to be any log files for chef-server to give me a hint as to where things are going wrong.

I've checked /proc/user_beancounters and the failcnt is 0 for everything there.

At this point I'm at a loss. Any ideas on what could be wrong or how I might get chef-server to cough up some useful information as to why its failing?

Answer (score 0):

In your chef-server config file, replace

```
log_level    :info
```

with

```
log_level    :debug
```

Now watch your log files to see where exactly it's failing.